# How to use GrumPHP with Magento2?

Tags: magento2, php, development

I would like to use [GrumPHP](https://github.com/phpro/grumphp) with my Magento 2, to be able to run simple verifications during my development, how can I do that?

Comment: I have written a detailed ruleset for Magento 2. Hope it helps:
https://adapttive.com/blog/grumphp-in-magento-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created this [basic tutorial](https://gist.github.com/rafaelstz/649922a3c98d7c2e781d52c771ccd566) about how to install and use in your Magento 2 project, but to start without a lot of errors I recommend using this method below.

#### 1 - Run in your Magento 2 root folder via terminal:

```
composer require "phpro/grumphp:^0.14" --dev
composer require nlubisch/grumphp-easycodingstandard --dev
composer require wearejust/grumphp-extra-tasks --dev
composer require jakub-onderka/php-parallel-lint --dev
```

#### 2 - Create a file called grumphp.yml in your project folder:

```
parameters:
  magento_dir: .
  bin_dir: "./vendor/bin"
  stop_on_failure: false
  ignore_unstaged_changes: false
  hide_circumvention_tip: false
  process_async_limit: 10
  process_async_wait: 1000
  process_timeout: 60
  tasks:
    composer:
      no_check_all: false
    git_blacklist:
      keywords:
        - "die"
        - "var_dump("
        - "exit"
        - "console.log("
        - "ObjectManager::getInstance"
      triggered_by: ['php', 'phtml', 'js']
    phpdoc: ~
    phpversion:
      project: '7.2'
    phplint:
      triggered_by: ['php', 'phtml']
    ecs:
      whitelist_patterns:
        - app/code
        - app/design
      fix: true
    xmllint: ~
    extensions:
      - Wearejust\GrumPHPExtra\Extension\Loader
      - NLubisch\GrumPHP\Extension
```

References: [Integer-net tutorial](https://www.integer-net.com/magento-2-automatic-code-quality-check-with-grumphp/)

Comment: Is it working for Magento 2.3.3 CE ?

Comment: Yes, it worked in my Magento 2.3 @VigneshBala

Comment: I have written a detailed ruleset for Magento 2. Hope it helps:
https://adapttive.com/blog/grumphp-in-magento-2